# Looking for direction to Build MySQL date query

Tags: mysql

reference Date:  **20.10.2015**

step 1: need the max date from PayTO table > max(PayTO)

step 2: check if this max(PayTO)  < reference Date  (20.10.2015)

```
MenTBL
======
TZ   |   Fname
===========
11    |  ZZZ
22    |  XXX
33    |  CCC
44    |  VVV


PayTbl
======
TZ   |  PayTO
===========
11    |  01/01/2015
11    |  03/05/2015
11    |  06/01/2016
22    |  01/01/2015
22    |  01/10/2015
33    |  01/01/2015
33    |  01/12/2015
44    |  01/01/2015
44    |  04/05/2015
44    |  18/10/2015
```

The result should be that way:

```
22    |  01/10/2015  |  XXX
44    |  18/10/2015  |  VVV
```

***Important note: PayTO is a string Field***

Comment: recommend converting PayTO to a date field as that is what it stores and far easier to use in that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**query**

```
select p.TZ, 
date_format(max(str_to_date(p.PayTO, '%d/%m/%Y')), '%d/%m/%Y') as dt,
m.FName
from PayTbl p
inner join MenTbl m
on p.TZ = m.TZ
group by p.TZ, m.FName
having max(str_to_date(p.PayTO, '%d/%m/%Y'))
<      DATE('2015-10-20')
;
```

**output**

```
+----+------------+-------+
| TZ |     dt     | FName |
+----+------------+-------+
| 22 | 01/10/2015 | XXX   |
| 44 | 18/10/2015 | VVV   |
+----+------------+-------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10ba6/22)**

---

**notes**

> due to the PayTO field type, have to use str_to_date. this will perform slower than the analogous query with date typed field

Comment: no worries. only small recommendation is to develop a script to migrate your data to store it in date type ( then query simplifies even further )